# MySQL, Concat int and save to veriable and use variable with 'IN' or 'NOT IN'

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I want to CONCAT value in `ID` column in string variable and use the variable with IN in SQL as under:

```
SET @ActID = CONCAT(CAST(5 AS CHAR),',',CAST(15 AS CHAR));

SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `ID` IN (@ActID);
```

It returns record having `ID` = 5 and ignore record having `ID` = 15.

Comment: Looks to me you are trusting on mysql auto datatype casting when using invalid types, stop doing that..

Comment: This [should work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3faf38b0962925ca53ef3efacdffcee7). What is your question?

Comment: I tried first without casting but result was same as it is now. Somewhere I noted that casting solved issue hence I tried.

Comment: GMB, I need both records in cursor for processing. Select SQL is without table name. If I add table name in it, it returns all records.

Answer (score 0):

`@ActID` is a comma separated list string literal and not a list of values.
So the list inside the parentheses of the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) operator contains only 1 value: `'5,15'`

- when you compare `5` to `'5,15'` the result is `TRUE`
- when you compare `15` to `'5,15'` the result is `FALSE`

because `'5,15'` is converted to the integer value `5` according to the rules described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).
What you want is the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SET @ActID = CONCAT(CAST(5 AS CHAR),',',CAST(15 AS CHAR));
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ID`,@ActID) > 0;
```

Change to `...= 0` for the equivalent of `NOT IN`.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f2ecf9c398283e3147edd0e2ebdb4309).
Note: `SET @ActID = CONCAT(5,',',15);` works fine.